# "A foreign key constraint fails" when converting a table from InnoDB to MyISAM

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

For some reason, the MySQL tables in my Django web application are using different formats, and it is causing foreign key constraint errors (like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178816/django-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails)).

Here is what the table formats look like.

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE `Name` in ('') ...
+----------------------------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+------------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------
| Name                       | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows   | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length  | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time         | Check_time          
+----------------------------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+------------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------
| table_0                    | MyISAM |      10 | Dynamic    |    341 |             83 |       28472 |  281474976710655 |        19456 |         0 |            346 | 2013-09-05 15:52:11 | 2014-01-10 14:17:18 | 2013-09-05 15:52:11 
| table_1                    | MyISAM |      10 | Dynamic    |  66422 |             49 |     3297260 |  281474976710655 |      2025472 |         0 |         141146 | 2013-07-20 19:12:24 | 2014-01-10 19:20:21 | 2013-07-20 19:12:27 
| table_2                    | MyISAM |      10 | Dynamic    |      3 |             53 |         160 |  281474976710655 |         3072 |         0 |              4 | 2013-07-20 19:12:27 | 2013-07-20 19:12:27 | 2013-07-20 19:12:27 
| table_3                    | MyISAM |      10 | Dynamic    |      8 |             99 |         796 |  281474976710655 |         3072 |         0 |             10 | 2013-07-20 19:12:27 | 2013-07-20 19:12:27 | 2013-07-20 19:12:27 
| table_4                    | MyISAM |      10 | Dynamic    |      0 |              0 |           0 |  281474976710655 |         1024 |         0 |              1 | 2013-07-20 19:12:27 | 2013-07-20 19:12:27 | 2013-07-20 19:12:27 
| table_5                    | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |                0 |        16384 |   7340032 |              1 | 2013-11-20 14:04:02 | NULL                | NULL                
| table_6                    | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |                0 |        16384 |   7340032 |              1 | 2013-11-20 14:03:39 | NULL                | NULL                
| table_7                    | MyISAM |      10 | Dynamic    |    860 |            125 |      107624 |  281474976710655 |        25600 |         0 |            977 | 2013-11-20 14:04:35 | 2014-01-06 18:32:57 | 2013-11-20 14:04:35 
| table_8                    | MyISAM |      10 | Fixed      |   6632 |             21 |      139272 | 5910974510923775 |       173056 |         0 |           6753 | 2013-07-20 19:16:47 | 2014-01-09 11:26:36 | 2013-07-20 19:16:47
```

I tried to update the table formats as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240977/changing-table-engine-in-mysql). But received the following error.

```
mysql> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; 
mysql> alter table ztrap_emailreportoptin engine = MyISAM;
ERROR 1217 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

How can I go about making the engine consistent between tables?

(Also, any idea how this happens to begin with?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MyISAM does not support foreign keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/myisam-storage-engine.html).
To convert to MyISAM, you would need to drop drop all foreign key contraints first.

Your error message tells you that your table `ztrap_emailreportoptin` either references another table, or is referenced by another table.

You can list such references with:

```sql
SELECT
    table_name, column_name, constraint_name,
    referenced_table_name, referenced_column_name
FROM information_schema.key_column_usage
WHERE referenced_table_name IS NOT NULL;
```

However, I would recommend converting your tables to InnoDB instead.

Comment: This worked and the explanation makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Try converting MyISAM ones to InnoDB, eg

```
alter table ztrap_emailreportoptin engine = InnoDB;
```

This way you'll have the server to enforce the foreign key checks on all tables.

Comment: Andy, that table already uses InnoDB. The rest of the tables use MyISAM and I'd like to make them all MyISAM.