# Django Admin Panel can not add any record to a table

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, django-admin

In my Django admin panel, whenever i want to add some records in a table i get this error :

> IntegrityError at /admin/pool/orders/add/
>
> (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`projectname`.`orders`, CONSTRAINT `orders_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`user_phone`) REFERENCES `users` (`phone`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)')

Here are my Models :

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    objects = jmodels.jManager()
    product = models.ForeignKey('Products', models.DO_NOTHING)
    user_phone = models.ForeignKey('Users', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='user_phone')
    order_date = jmodels.jDateField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    count = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Orders'
        verbose_name_plural = "user orders"

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s------- (%s)' % (self.user_phone,self.status)


class Users(models.Model):
    objects = jmodels.jManager()
    phone = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=11)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    family = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    nationalcode = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    profilepic = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    profiletext = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    bons = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, null=True)
    charge = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, null=True)
    registerdate = jmodels.jDateField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Users'
        verbose_name_plural = "Users"

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s ---- (%s)' % (self.name,self.family,self.phone)
```

**Additional:** 
Along with this I have another issue. It is that I have 150 records in orders table, but I can't see them in Django admin panel, instead it just displays the count.

Comment: Can you show the models you have used? The error maybe caused because you are trying to add data to your `orders` table with invalid `user_phone` value.

Comment: You are not adding one of the `ForeignKeyField` which is required while saving

Comment: @Sanip I Edited the question , so you can see my models

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari I'm exactly adding them , and no record is missing .

Comment: In your database(not admin panel or shell), check if the tables are created.

Comment: @Sanip Yes they are exists .

Comment: @T.Pool which database are you using? Is it MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You error can be caused due to mismatch in STORAGE_ENGIENE. I think there are some tables of INNODB and some tables of MyISAM. Try converting them into a consistent type.

Further if this is not the error, then it is being caused due to forward references in your database. If this is the cause, then you can turn off the foreign key checks by editing your Django settings as:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
                ...         
               'OPTIONS': {
                         "init_command": "SET foreign_key_checks = 0;",
                },
       }
}
```

For more details, you can refer this post: [Django "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178816/django-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails)

**EDIT:**

To get the value of `phone` in your `user_phone` field, you need to use `ForeignKey.to_field` in your `Orders` model as:

```
user_phone = models.ForeignKey('Users', to_field='phone')
```

This is required because Django uses the primary key of the `User` model to store the value in `user_phone` of `Orders` model. Using the above mentioned script helps to get the value of the field you desire in the foreign key field.

While doing so, you need to ensure that `phone` field of the User model is has `unique=True` set.

Check this link for official Django documentation [to_field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field)

Comment: Now I can add user orders , but there is a problem with it , when i select user phone and want to save order , instead of user phone , it saves users id , what is this problem is for ?

Comment: Yesssssssssssss, it solves my other problem too , very very thank you .